# Which react lifecycle method to use

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a scenario where I have a landing page, Page-X, on which a component x1 gets data from fetch API call , which I have handled in `componentDidMount()` method , and until the data is fetched, show a loading gif.

Now when I click a component y1 on Page-X, a modal opens , and on-close modal, the loading gif comes back for component x1 , and looks like the redux store is cleared from where I was getting the fetched data for x1 (allallBatchesFromDB - see below)?
So do i need to make api call again when I return back from the modal ? If yes , which life-cycle method should I use ?
TIA

```
 componentDidMount = () => {

     store.dispatch( getDataDBNew(this.props.bugDetails.agentName, this.props.bugDetails.bugId, true,
                true, true, false, 'PFM'));
     console.log("callsed for "+this.props.bugDetails.bugId);
 }
```

render part : -

```
let allallBatchesFromDB = store.getState().batchFromDBReducer.batches;

     (allallBatchesFromDB) ?

         <div>
        <Componentx1 /> 
          </div>
            : 

            <img width={40} height={40} src={loadinglinear}/>

                }
```

fetch :

```
export function getDataDBNew(agentName,bugId,isRegressionChecked,
  isSegmentWiseChecked,isFeatureWiseChecked,
  isDirectCallRequired,featureName){
  return (dispatch)=>{
    axios.post('apiurl', {
      "agentName": agentName,
      "bugId": bugId,
      "isRegressionChecked": isRegressionChecked,
      "isSegmentWiseChecked": isSegmentWiseChecked,
      "isFeatureWiseChecked": isFeatureWiseChecked,
      "isDirectCallRequired": isDirectCallRequired,
      "featureName": featureName,
      "isDBCall" : true  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("got batch new reponse from db"+ JSON.stringify(response));
    return dispatch(fetchBatchFromDBNew(bugId,response));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("getting errrorooror"+error);
  });

}
}

export function fetchBatchFromDBNew(bugId,response){
  return {
    type : ACTIONS_TYPES.FETCH_ALL_BATCH_FROM_DB_ALL_BUGS,
    batches : response.data,
    bugId : bugId
  };
}
```

reducer :

```
import {ACTIONS_TYPES} from '../Actions/action';

function batchFromDBReducer(state={batches:{},allBatchesFromDB:{},regressionBatchFromDB:{},segmentBatchFromDB:{},featureBatchFromDB:{}},action){

    var bool =false ;
    if(action.allBatchesFromDB){
        bool = true ;
    }
      switch(action.type){

        case ACTIONS_TYPES.FETCH_ALL_BATCH_FROM_DB_ALL_BUGS:
              return {
                batches: {
                    ...state.batches,
                    [action.bugId]: action.batches
                  }
              }


        default:
        return {
            defaultBatchFromDB : state.regressionBatchFromDB
        }

    }

}

export default batchFromDBReducer;
```

**Latest Edit**
Also i have following line of code in my constructor :

```
        store.subscribe(() => this.forceUpdate());
```

Comment: are you using different reducer for both or single one? Show full code of redux too

Comment: added my fetch api and reducer code

Comment: are you toggling between loader and component ?

Comment: not toggling , just showing loader if data is not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `FETCH_ALL_BATCH_FROM_DB_ALL_BUGS` is there any other redux action that is dispatched during this time ? If so that will clear previously fetched data as the default handler in `batchFromDBReducer` reducer does not extend over the previous state. Update the default handle with the following and see if it solves the issue :

```
return {...state, defaultBatchFromDB : state.regressionBatchFromDB}
```

If the reducer is intended to function that way, then upon modal close, inspect what is causing the re-render in pageX. If it is a prop change, you can fire the fetch in `componentWillReceiveProps`. If it's a state change do the same in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: thanks , as you said , there were other actions being dispatched . So i have created a new reducer now for my case and now store is intact .

Comment: key thing to be noted was " is there any other redux action that is dispatched during this time ? If so that will clear previously fetched data as the default handler" , so i changed my reducer to return the desired data in default as well